# How do i get my interface back to normal?

Tags: interface

[image]

I don't really get what else to put here because its pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Try Edit > Preferences > Interface and set Display > Resolution Scale to 1.0.

Comment: its so zoomed in i cant select it from the menu

Comment: If a menu is cut off, hover over it and use the scroll wheel (scroll or click+drag) to see the rest of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can closely see the "E"[image: "Image"]
in the screenshot as **scurest** said

> Try Edit > Preferences > Interface and set Display > Resolution Scale to 1.0 - scurest

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is just to reset the Blender preferences by locating and removing the `userpref.blend` file. On Windows this is typically found in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version>\config`

[image: user pref]

Remove the file and Blender will automatically revert back to the default preferences the next time you start it.